# Gesture Recognizer in prototype cell doesn't work

Tags: uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a prototype cell with an UIImageView, when user tap this ImageView, app should display a Collection View where user can select an alternative icon for the cell. So, in UITableViewCell I added a Gesture Recognizer:

```
internal let iconTappedGR = UITapGestureRecognizer()
```

then I implemented it in table's cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.iconTappedGR.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeIcon))
cell.iconView.gestureRecognizers = []
cell.iconView.gestureRecognizers!.append(cell.iconTappedGR)
```

and I added a changeIcon function

```
func changeIcon () { 
    print("imageView tapped!") 
}
```

trouble is that it doesn't works; I tried even using storyboard but is the same...where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using

```
cell.iconView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36495864/2085352 to a question posted 30 minutes later than mine!