# UITapGesture on UIImageview not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm trying too make UIImage as button using UITapGesture.

```
let contactSegueIdentifier = "showContactSegue"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    initTapGestureRec()
}

func initTapGestureRec() {
    let tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("recognizeTapGesture:"))
    brandMenuContactImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func recognizeTapGesture(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(contactSegueIdentifier, sender: self)
}
```

When I run and tap the image, nothing happened. Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Try enabling user interaction on the UIImageView... Either in Storyboard or with `userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: Oh yeah, it's worked. but how to prepareSegue? @Byron Coetsee

Comment: and don't forget to call super.viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `userInteractionEnabled` true on your image and try

```
brandMenuContactImage.userInteractionEnabled  = true
```

**objective-C**

```
 brandMenuContactImage.userInteractionEnabled  = YES;
```

**Update**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  brandMenuContactImage.userInteractionEnabled  = true
initTapGestureRec()
}
```

Comment: what if I want to pass data?

Comment: ya you can pass, you can get the item using `sender.view.tag` u get current index after that u can pass

Comment: how to pass variable? can you give some example?

Comment: @lamfete - can update your question for which type u need , for example if I tap the Image what u want to perform